# The Opencart setOutput function doesn't print the twig template file

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I'm trying to create a Opencart module that show a custom view page. I'm not trying to modify a file, but creating a new one.

My Controller is:

```
class ControllerSaleSalesAnalytics extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('sale/sales_analytics');
        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
        $this->load->model('sale/sales_analytics');

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('sale/sales_analytics'));
    }
}
```

And my twig template file is:

```
{{ header }}{{ column_left }}
<div>
  <h1>Custom page!</h1>
</div>
{{ footer }}
```

However, the Opencart `setOutput` function doesn't print my template file.

I already gave the group permissions on the Opencart settings.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you added language file for this ? : $this->load->language('sale/sales_analytics');

Comment: Yes, I did. The language file works perfectly. The system doesn't shows any error, but the twig template file doesn't show by the function, so I'm viewing a page with a ´input´ and a status `select`.

Comment: most of time this happens when module name not being loaded from language file..!
which version of opencart you are using ?

Comment: I'm using the 3.0.3.3 version.

Comment: Your code should work! If you  do not forget corresponding model file and corresponding language file. Or comment load of this files in controller file. And the main problem seems your forget set access and modify permissions in your admin dashboard for user groups. And do not forget clear cache in admin dashboard (blue gear in the right upper corner) and also refresh modifications.

Comment: Yes, @K.B. - the code works. I already solved the problem clearing the Template cache when I finded the gear icon in the Dashboard, as you said. I'm very new on OpenCart development and I didn't knew about this feature. Thank you.